# Infinite collectionview cells don't have unique index paths

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, nsindexpath

Hi guys and merry christmas so i'm currently using this library within my project to create an horizontal infinite scrolling collectionview.

**Infinite Collectionview library**
https://github.com/masoapps/infinite-uicollectionview

The problem that i'm having is that each cell in this collectionview doesn't have an unique indexpath. Meaning that i can't seem to access the correct cell and do something to the controls within it.

For example i'm trying to bold a label within the cell that has been pressed.

**Function to bold the label**

```
    func setNRestLbl(collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: NSIndexPath){

        collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)

// Testing code to see the indexpaths which are visible
                print("Visible cells are - \(cell.newsTypeLbl.text) - NSIndexPath is \(indexPath.row)")
                for cell in collectionView.visibleCells() as! [newsTypeCell] {
                if self.cellKey == cell.newsTypeLbl.text! {

                    cell.newsTypeLbl.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 14)
                }
                else{
                    cell.newsTypeLbl.font =  UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 14)
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

The weird behaviour is that the collectionview is scrolling to the right item but applying the bold from the function above to the incorrect cell with the label inside it's applying it to the last cell rather than the cell which should be in the middle because all the indexpaths are the same i'm assuming it's just trying to guess which is the correct one.

I've also realised when debugging that there is two cells that is appearing rather than one could this be an issue as to why it is struggling to go to target the correct cell? Screenshot below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: is the `Design` `Development` `Social` labels stacked together?

Answer (score 0):

Cells already have a `selected` property, make use of that. Also, don't use a button inside the cells, just use a label for `Design`, `Development` etc, and set the font in the overridden selected property.
So, in your collection view cell subclass:

```
override public var selected: Bool {
    didSet {
        methodThatUpdatesLabelFont()
    }
}



func methodThatUpdatesLabelFont() {
    if selected {
        self.label.font = ...
    } else {
        self.label.font = ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey mate so i've tried this but i'm still getting the same effect. I think it maybe part of the source code in the InfiniteCollectionView.swift which in generating the cells but i can't seem to figure out what.

Comment: Hey mate i've edited the question showing the debugging area, this now shows the debugging area. Like i said in the last comment even with your solution the behaviour is the same maybe this screenshot has something to do with it.